# how to format a date in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

How can i format the date "01-SEP-2011" on "2011-09-01" format in shell script?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$ date --date='01-SEP-2011' +%Y-%m-%d
```

Comment: That assumes you have the GNU coreutils version of the date command.  If you're running bash, you probably do -- but it might not be installed by default on MacOS, for example.  (I don't know whether bash is installed by default, but there's no non-GNU version of `bash`; there are non-GNU versions of `date`.)

Comment: `date ... +%F` also works (but I think `+%Y-%m-%d` is a bit more portable).

Answer (score 1):

If you have Ruby installed on the target system you could do this:

```bash
#/bin/bash
read DATE # 01-SEP-2011
set DATE=$(ruby -rdate -e "puts Date.parse('$DATE').to_s")
echo $DATE # 2011-09-01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kent$  date +%F -d "01-SEP-2011" 
2011-09-01
```