# Convert the value of variable in date format in shell

Tags: shell

I have variable and value of that variable is coming like 20130112. i know that it is a Date but i don't know how can i convert it into a valid date in shell script .

The value of the field is : 20130112
Result should be : 12-Jan-13

Please help me on this.

Comment: *Duplicate:* http://stackoverflow.com/q/7502822/1563422

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'date' command on linux.

```
date -d 20130112
```

will print it in the default date format on your system. Check other formating options on the 'man' page of date.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$ date -j -f "%Y%m%d" "20130112" +"%d-%b-%y"
12-Jan-13
```